# C#/REST API - Could not delete file on Sharepoint 365 site

Tags: c#, rest, sharepoint, office365api, http-delete

I am trying to download and delete files from starepoint document library. Reading works fine for all sites ("root", 1st level sites, 2nd level sites), for example:

- oursharepoint.sharepoint.com
- oursharepoint.sharepoint.com/DEV
- oursharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/DEV

Also deleting is OK for "root" and 1st level sites. But, if I want to delete a file from 2nd level site, an ERROR 403 FORBIDDEN is returned.

Any idea what's wrong?

GET URL:

```
oursharepoint.sharepoint.com//sites/DEV/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared documents')/Files('Document.docx')/$value
```

DELETE URL:

```
oursharepoint.sharepoint.com//sites/DEV/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared documents')/Files('Document.docx')
```

Code for deleting:

```
var sReq = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
if (sReq != null)
{
sReq.Method = "DELETE";
sReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
sReq.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
sReq.CookieContainer.Add(IssuedRtfaCookie);
sReq.CookieContainer.Add(IssuedSamlCookie);

sReq.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", RequestDigest);
sReq.Headers.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "DELETE");
sReq.Headers.Add("IF-MATCH", "*");

var sRes = sReq.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think "2nd level" folder considered as a file, not a folder. Get a list of all files in the library and delete one by one